# browser.loadurl not working after onReceivedError

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Hi currently i want load my own html file from asset when my webview onReceivedError and then loadurl again after button click at the html file

Firstly, i call this during onCreate

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewLoginBrowser());
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new ErrorPageInterface(), "AndroidErrorPage");
```

I turn off my WIFI and then in my onReceivedError, i save the failingUrl and load my customized HTML file from asset

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(errorCode) + "\n" + description + "\n" + failingUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ErrorPage = failingUrl;
            browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Error Page.html");    
            }
```

then in my HTML code, i turn on my WIFI and there is a button i press to call android so that it can load url again

```
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    AndroidErrorPage.ReloadPage("ON");
}

</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFF">
<p> That is an error </p>
<p> Make sure you have a working internet connection. </p>
<p> Please click the button below to try again </p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" style="width:200px;height:200px">Refresh</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and lastly the not working part, the reloadPage called from HTML should start loadUrl but it didn't and the Toast not even show up (however if i remove the line browser.loadUrl(ErrorPage); the code is working fine and toast is showing up)

```
public class ErrorPageInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void ReloadPage(String page) {
            browser.loadUrl(ErrorPage);
            // String currentpage = browser.getUrl();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), page + "\n" + ErrorPage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

basically i what i want is loadurl->onreceivederror->show my html file->click a button on the html file->loadurl again on android, the last part didnt work, anyone has idea why?

Comment: You said not working part is the javascript interface? while your question says your customized errorpage is not loading. What exactly is not happening?

Comment: Sorry confusing description, i changed the description you can try to look again, basically i what i want is loadurl->onreceivederror->show my html file->click a button on the html file->loadurl again on android, the  last part didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `browser.loadUrl(ErrorPage);`

Use -

```
browser.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/secondpage.html");
                    }
                });
```

Because browser.loadUrl() was getting called on non-UI thread 'JavaBridge'.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the my confusing description, what you say that part is working, basically i what i want is loadurl->onreceivederror->show my html file->click a button on the html file->loadurl again on android, the last part (loadurl again) didnt work